# Emulating an RS232 port on Windows 11

Tags: windows, serial-port, emulation

I want to develop a personal project which includes a heavyweight scale.
This scale usually connects to the computer using an RS232 port.

I want to learn how to read/write information into one.
But I can't physically connect to the scale. I thought of buying a smaller scale and do my tests on it, but it is just not practical.

Would you suggest an emulator for such port?

My operating system is Windows 11.

Comment: Simply attach a real RS-232 port using a USB adapter.  No "*emulation*" involved.

Comment: I think your explanation is insufficient. In other words, there is no real thing now, or it cannot be prepared during development, so it is not possible to connect a heavyweight scale and try it. Isn't that what you mean? And instead, you want to develop and test your system with a small scale as a heavyweight scale? However, if you also don't have such a small scale, what you should do is create a simulator as a heavyweight scale device, not an RS232C port emulation.

Comment: Hello @kunif how can I create such an emulation?

Comment: It would be good to obtain a document that defines and explains the specifications of the communication protocol and command response of the heavyweight scale, and create an application that performs communication according to the behavior of the scale. As for the communication method, if you purchase two USB serial dongles and install the device driver as @sawdust wrote, you can communicate using the OS standard API on both sides.